# error using json_normalize on opened file

Tags: python, json, pandas

Why can I use the json_normalize function in a list written directly in the script but I can't do it with the same data as an opened file?

Json sample:

```
resp = {"pagina": 1, "total_de_paginas": 3, "registros": 500, "total_de_registros": 1052, "produto_servico_cadastro":
[{"aliquota_cofins":0,
  "aliquota_ibpt":0,
  "aliquota_icms":0,
  "aliquota_pis":0,
  "altura":5,
  "bloqueado":"N",
  "bloquear_exclusao":"N",
  "cest":"",
  "cfop":"",
  "codInt_familia":"",
  "codigo":"10",
  "codigo_beneficio":"",
  "codigo_familia":3250197559,
  "codigo_produto":3250200206,
  "codigo_produto_integracao":"8531613751",
  "componentes_kit":[
     {
        "codigo_componente":3323761053,
        "codigo_produto_componente":3250202406,
        "local_estoque_componente":3244295942,
        "quantidade_componente":1,
        "valor_unitario_componente":13.1
     },
     {
        "codigo_componente":3253472053,
        "codigo_produto_componente":3250202411,
        "local_estoque_componente":3244295942,
        "quantidade_componente":1,
        "valor_unitario_componente":13.1
     }]}]}
```

script 1:

```
df_= resp['produto_servico_cadastro']
df_1 = pd.json_normalize(df_, record_path = ['componentes_kit'])
```

script 2:

In this example, I copied the contents of the resp variable and created a json file

```
f = open('/content/data.json')
dft = json.load(f)['produto_servico_cadastro']
dft_1 = pd.json_normalize(dft, record_path=['componentes_kit'])
```

results in

```
KeyError: 'componentes_kit'
```

Comment: Clearly the contents of `df_` and `dft` are different. But you didn't show us what they contain, so we cannot help you. Help us to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to reproduce. No problem found.

```
>>> from pprint import pp
>>> pp(resp, sort_dicts=True)
{'pagina': 1,
 'produto_servico_cadastro': [{'aliquota_cofins': 0,
                               'aliquota_ibpt': 0,
                               'aliquota_icms': 0,
                               'aliquota_pis': 0,
                               'altura': 5,
                               'bloqueado': 'N',
                               'bloquear_exclusao': 'N',
                               'cest': '',
                               'cfop': '',
                               'codInt_familia': '',
                               'codigo': '10',
                               'codigo_beneficio': '',
                               'codigo_familia': 3250197559,
                               'codigo_produto': 3250200206,
                               'codigo_produto_integracao': '8531613751',
                               'componentes_kit': [{'codigo_componente': 3323761053,
                                                    'codigo_produto_componente': 3250202406,
                                                    'local_estoque_componente': 3244295942,
                                                    'quantidade_componente': 1,
                                                    'valor_unitario_componente': 13.1},
                                                   {'codigo_componente': 3253472053,
                                                    'codigo_produto_componente': 3250202411,
                                                    'local_estoque_componente': 3244295942,
                                                    'quantidade_componente': 1,
                                                    'valor_unitario_componente': 13.1}]}],
 'registros': 500,
 'total_de_paginas': 3,
 'total_de_registros': 1052}
>>> 
>>> fspec = '/tmp/data.json'
>>> 
>>> with open(fspec, 'w') as fout:
...     json.dump(resp, fout, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> f = open(fspec)
>>> dft = json.load(f)['produto_servico_cadastro']
>>> dft_1 = pd.json_normalize(dft, record_path=['componentes_kit'])
>>> 
>>> dft_1
   codigo_componente  codigo_produto_componente  local_estoque_componente  quantidade_componente  valor_unitario_componente
0         3323761053                 3250202406                3244295942                      1                       13.1
1         3253472053                 3250202411                3244295942                      1                       13.1
>>>
>>> pp(dft, sort_dicts=True)
[{'aliquota_cofins': 0,
  'aliquota_ibpt': 0,
  'aliquota_icms': 0,
  'aliquota_pis': 0,
  'altura': 5,
  'bloqueado': 'N',
  'bloquear_exclusao': 'N',
  'cest': '',
  'cfop': '',
  'codInt_familia': '',
  'codigo': '10',
  'codigo_beneficio': '',
  'codigo_familia': 3250197559,
  'codigo_produto': 3250200206,
  'codigo_produto_integracao': '8531613751',
  'componentes_kit': [{'codigo_componente': 3323761053,
                       'codigo_produto_componente': 3250202406,
                       'local_estoque_componente': 3244295942,
                       'quantidade_componente': 1,
                       'valor_unitario_componente': 13.1},
                      {'codigo_componente': 3253472053,
                       'codigo_produto_componente': 3250202411,
                       'local_estoque_componente': 3244295942,
                       'quantidade_componente': 1,
                       'valor_unitario_componente': 13.1}]}]
>>>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the pandas version is affecting the result?
I'm programming through google colab, the installed version is 1.3.5

Comment: I don't believe so. Your file content appears to be different from my file, despite the fact that I created my file according to your instructions. For the record, I see 1.4.3. in `pd.__version__`

Comment: when I try to process all the data I get the Key_error because not all items have the "components_kits" field

Comment: That brings us back to the MRE topic. It is important for OP to run the posted example, pretending to be some random SO user, to verify the example makes sense. Here, the example data was incomplete, it did not exhibit the characteristic of interest. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Understood! I will improve for the next questions. Thank you for your help and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This does actually work.

You will notice the key differences is how I have read the data (compared to the example code: `script2`).

In particular:

- read the data from the file into `data` variable with `f.read()`.
- `json.loads` (copared to `json.load`)

If i copy the contents into a `data.json` file i can read it in exactly the same way like this:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

file = "C:\\test\\data.json"

with open(file) as f:
    data = f.read()

dft = json.loads(data)
dft = dft['produto_servico_cadastro']
dft_1 = pd.json_normalize(dft, record_path=['componentes_kit'])
df_1
```

And it produces the same dataframe:

```
   codigo_componente  codigo_produto_componente  local_estoque_componente  \
0         3323761053                 3250202406                3244295942   
1         3253472053                 3250202411                3244295942   

   quantidade_componente  valor_unitario_componente  
0                      1                       13.1  
1                      1                       13.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thanks to you I managed to find a solution

Comment: you are welcome,  glad to have helped.